# After having remeshed and smoothened out my sculpture, holes started appearing in it

Tags: sculpting, remesh

I was sculpting, I needed to remesh it, which I did.

Then I used the smooth tool to smooth it out but these holes starting appearing randomly. I tried to fix them but I don't know what to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the surface become so thin, that after remeshing or adding new brush strokes it creates holes.
There are some solutions to that.

1. Increase the resolution amount while remeshing.
2. Increase thickness of that area to avoid that issue. Use the Inflate brush and just go all around that thin area to make sure that it becomes thicker. After remesh of `course.
3. In your brush settings, enable "front faces only".
4. Enable "fix poles" in remesh settings.

[image]

[image]